# Install virtualenvwrapper for Python 2.7 and 3.6 simultaneously

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

How does one install `virtualenvwrapper` for both `Python 2.7` and `3.6` versions? My default Python environment is `Python 3.6` and as such `virtualenvwrapper` is installed for `Python 3.6` and not `2.7`. I'm using `macOS Sierra 10.12.6`.

Comment: Use pip3 for the python version, I am not familiar with Mac OS but I believe this should work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need only [install `virtualenvwrapper` once](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#basic-installation). See the warning about installing on your base Python installation.

Using Homebrew package manager install `python2` and `python3`.

Making a virtual environment is a matter of passing a flag.

```
# make py3
mkvirtualenv py3 --python=python3

# make py2
mkvirtualenv py2 --python=python2
```