# Initializing virtualenvwrapper for Python 3.6 on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I would like to use virtualenvwrapper with Python 3.6, however, I am working on a Mac which defaults to using Python 2.7 and I am having issues. Here's what I have done so far. Using the following commands, I have found the locations of where each Python version is saved:

```
>> which python 
>> /usr/bin/python

>> which python3
>> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

I have successfully installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper using:

```
>> pip3 install virtualenv
>> pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

I then search for the location of virtualenv and virtualenv wrapper to confirm their locations:

```
>> pip3 show virtualenv
>> Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

>> pip3 show virtualenvwrapper
>> Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

If I go to this site-packages directory there is the following:

```
virtualenvwrapper
    |--- __pycache__
    |--- hook_loader.py
    |--- project.py
    |--- user_scripts.py
virtualenvwrapper-4.8.2-py2.7-nspkg.pth
virtualenvwrapper-4.8.2.dist-info
```

According to virtualenvwrapper's documentation, I should add the following to my shell startup file to ensure initialization, changing virtualenvwrapper's path to the one set on my machine:

```
 export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I then searched for where virtualenvwrapper.sh is actually located (for some reason, it is not located where the virtualenvwrapper module is installed):

```
>> which virtualenvwrapper.sh
>> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I changed my .bashrc file using:

```
>> nano ~./bashrc
```

Copied in the following:

```
# script for virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I then opened up a new terminal and ran:

```
>> source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
```

Which gave me:

```
  /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.
```

What I don't understand is why virtualenvwrapper needs to be located at /usr/bin/python3 which is not a directory. Since it is in bin, it is also impossible for me to make it a directory. Additionally, the virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader is not where virtualenvwrapper.sh is which I think may be causing an issue.

I also tried creating a symbolic link to /usr/local/bin because some people stated that it solved their issue but this didn't solve mine:

```
sudo ln /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Another issue altogether is whether or not I need to install it using pip3 if I want to use virtualenvwrapper for Python3. For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917859/install-virtualenvwrapper-for-python-2-7-and-3-6-simultaneously) states that you only need to pass a flag, however, you should also be wary of installing it on your base Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

to `.bashrc` and execute the command in the terminal. That sets the path to Python interpreter for `virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: I still got the same issue: `/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
`

Comment: Quick question : when i run which -a python3 i get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`
`/usr/local/bin/python3`
`/usr/bin/python3` what does this mean?

Comment: @kd12345 Please do not abuse comments for off-topic questions. Comments are for discussions of the question or the answer.

Comment: @phd sorry about that, should i use the answer you suggested or this `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7`